# Intuition for homotopy (co)limits in triangulated categories

Tags: reference-request, intuition, homological-algebra, homotopy-theory, triangulated-categories

The following definition is taken from Daniel Murfet's [Triangulated Categories Part I](http://therisingsea.org/notes/TriangulatedCategories.pdf) notes.

> Let $\mathcal T$ be a triangulated category with countable coproducts.
>   Suppose we are given a sequence of objects and arrows in $\mathcal T$
>   $$X_0\overset{j_1}{\longrightarrow}X_1\overset{j_2}{\longrightarrow}X_2\overset{j_3}{\longrightarrow}X_3\overset{j_4}{\longrightarrow}\cdots$$
>   Let $\mu:\bigoplus _{i=0}^\infty \longrightarrow \bigoplus
> _{i=0}^\infty X_i$ be the arrow induced out of the first coproduct by the arrows $j_{i+1}:X_i\rightarrow X_{i+1}$. That is, $\mu u_i=u_{i+1}j_{i+1}$ where $u_i$ is the injection of $X_i$ into the
>   coproduct. A *homotopy colimit* of the sequence, denoted
>   $\underrightarrow{\mathrm{holim}}X_i$, is a homotopy cokernel of
>   $1-\mu$. That is, it an arrow $v:\bigoplus_{i=0}^\infty X_i\rightarrow \underrightarrow{\mathrm{holim}}X_i$ fitting into a distinguished
>   triangle $$\bigoplus_{i=0}^\infty X_i \overset{1-\mu}{\longrightarrow}
>  \bigoplus_{i=0}^\infty X_i \overset{v}{\longrightarrow}
>  \underrightarrow{\mathrm{holim}} \overset{w}{\longrightarrow} \Sigma
>  \left\{ \bigoplus_{i=0}^\infty X_i \right\}$$

I'm looking for intuition for this definition, and also for proof that it coincides with the general definition as a derived functor of the usual colimit functor. References are welcome.

Comment: The analogue to think about is an abelian category with countable coproducts. How would you construct colimits for sequences using use coproducts and cokernels?